# Non-linear (negatively cubic) wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I've come across a question which asks me to solve the following non-linear wave equation:

$u_{tt}-c^2\cdot u_{xx}=\frac{\alpha}{u^3} -\beta \cdot u $

I tried using the separation of variables method, and substituting a travelling periodic wave solution, but both methods didn't work for me. Is there a certain substitution for such equations? Or does this equation belong to a specific type of non-linear wave equations?

Would appreciate any hints as how to solve it.

Comment: what do you get by substituting $u(x,t) = e^{ i \omega (t \pm x/c)} v(x,t)$ ?

Comment: I reached a rather more formidable-looking pde which includes first order partial derivatives and complex terms... I have never really used such a substitution before so don't really know how to go on from here.